# Instagram API Subscription For First Time ( get real time update )

Tags: asp.net, ajax, instagram-api

I have registered my APP on Instagram and i Successfully retrieved recent media using: 
https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/self/media/recent/?access_token=ACCESS-TOKEN

Now I want to Subscribe user to instgram to get real time update , i tried this :

```
        $.ajax({                                                                   
            url: "https://api.instagram.com/v1/subscriptions/?client_id=MyClientID&client_secret=MyClientSecret&object=user&aspect=media&verify_token=MyToken&callback_url=MyService.ashx",
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: "jsonp",
            success: function (data) {
                console.log(data);
            },
            error: function (errorText) {
                console.log(errorText);
            }
        });

    });
```

the Post request above prints : {"meta": {"code": 200}, "data": []} 
which means it is a  successful request

but i didn't receive any request from Instagram on my callback URL to send me the [ hub.challenge ]

Instagram subscription API :

Create a Subscription

To create a subscription, you make a POST request to the subscriptions endpoint.

[image]

Where I went Wrong ??

Comment: what is your callback url? I hope it is not a local one.

Comment: https://336ef02f.ngrok.io/somthing.ashx and  i tried  https://336ef02f.ngrok.io/something.aspx

Comment: If you are using ngrok to expose your local env to internet, you would need to make sure your port is available from outside your local network. Make also sure you have started your app before sending image to instagram. I did some experiments with instagram realtime subscriptions and if I am not wrong, Instagram tries to send the notification once to the callback url, if the app is not up, the notification gets lost. Have you also tried with http instead of https?

Comment: I tried both http and https , and i have checked the port and it is working from outside, but problem remains

Comment: Can you also check whether you still have in place the subscription? https://api.instagram.com/v1/subscriptions?client_secret=CLIENT-SECRET&client_id=CLIENT-ID Also, according the Instagram API, when subscribing, you have to receive something else in the data not an empty array https://www.instagram.com/developer/subscriptions/

Comment: (Can you also check whether you still have in place the subscription?) if you mean by this question that i already have established the subscription , the answer is no am trying to establish the subscription !!

Comment: so, if you don't have a subscription, how come do you want to get the updates from a subscription that is not set up yet? I am a bit lost I think

Comment: Sorry if i lost you , i think i was unclear .
what i want is to ( Create a Subscription ) for the first time !!
i supposed to receive this :

https://your-callback.com/url/?hub.mode=subscribe&hub.challenge=15f7d1a91c1f40f8a748fd134752feb3&hub.verify_token=myVerifyToken

but i don't get it !!

Comment: Are you echoing the value for the param hub.challenge?

Comment: i don't RECEIVE it in the first place , that is my problem

Comment: This is what I get when requesting your callback url https://puu.sh/toj2K/e605364bc5.png

Comment: I don't know which is your verifyToken but I am still getting an error when requesting https://336ef02f.ngrok.io/AccessToken.ashx?hub.mode=subscribe&hub.challenge=15f7d1a91c1f40f8a748fd134752feb3&hub.verify_token=myVerifyToken

Comment: man it doesn't seem that we understand each other , so can you please give me an example on ( creating a subscription ) for the first time !!

Comment: The documentation is quite clear https://www.instagram.com/developer/subscriptions/ but I don't think your application is responding as it should be. When creating the subcription, your callback url should only spit out the parameter hub.challenge that you received (after checking of course the verifyToken is the right one)